# How does one set the default parameterization of a class?

Tags: raku

The `^parameterize` method allows one to parameterize a class with some given information, such as a role.

```
my role A[::T = Mu] { }

my class B {
    method ^parameterize(Mu \base, Mu \type) {
        my \what := base.^mixin(A[type]);
        what.^set_name(base.^name ~ '[' ~ type.^name ~ ']');
        what
    }
}

dd B[Int];        # B[Int]
dd B[Int].^roles; # (A[Int],)
```

However, I haven't been able to find a way to make the **unparameterized** version of `B` do the *unparameterized* version of role `A`.

```
dd B;        # B
dd B.^roles; # (), want to see (A[Mu],)
```

I tried to add a `^compose` method, but that only gets called if the class is parameterized.

Suggestions very welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that you can't (at least not in the foreseeable future).  So I took a step back to see what I actually wanted to achieve.  And **that** turned out to be possible:

```
my role A[::T] {
    method foobar() { T }
}

my class B {
    method foobar() { Mu }

    method ^parameterize(Mu \base, Mu \type) {
        my \what := base.^mixin(A[type]);
        what.^set_name(base.^name ~ '[' ~ type.^name ~ ']');
        what
    }
}

dd B.foobar;       # Mu
dd B[Int].foobar;  # Int
```

The method `foobar` is by default supplied by the `B` class.  If one parameterizes the `B` class, it will mix in another version of the `foobar` method (which shadows the original method), which returns the type given with the parameterization.

In the end, this gave me the framework for allowing parameterization of `QuantHash`es, a long standing request of my own, and recently others.